# The icon did not appear

Tags: css

I have this code and I want to use the "menu icon" in the code, but it did not appear, and I did not know why?

And this file contains a set of instructions containing the icon and other things, and as it is clear, the icon was placed in the Navbar, but it did not appear

```html
<html DOCTYPE="html5">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Website Using Flexbox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimony</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <box-icon name="menu" type="solid"></box-icon>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "404 Cannot find "/svg/solid/bxs-menu.svg" in boxicons@2.0.9" it failed to find the svg file. Are you sure that it's present and it's this name ?

Comment: It works if you remove `type="solid"` because "solid" doesn't have any menu icons.

Comment: i remove it , but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the "Font Awesome" library

Answer (score 0):

It seems element with attribute name="menu" has not attribute type="solid".  However, element with attribute name="menu" has attribute type="regular" .
Removing type="solid" or swapping it to type="regular" will make it work.

```
<box-icon name="menu" type="regular"></box-icon>
<box-icon name="menu"></box-icon>
```

Comment: no , it doesn't still work.

Answer (score 0):

check demo in **Full Page**
put your boxicons script in `<head></head>` tag and it will start working here is the working demo update me if any change is required.

```html
<html doctype="html5">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website Using Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimony</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          <box-icon name="menu" type="solid"></box-icon>
            
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```